# Child theme style.css from parent doesn't transfer

Tags: html, css, wordpress, parent-child, stylesheet

I am relatively new to WordPress and am using a theme from ThemeForest which is the builder responsive multi-purpose theme. I created the child theme, selected and activated it from the dashboard. The issue I am having is that the style formatting of the header, menu and footer areas don't transfer to the child theme.

My site is brewer2inspect.com

I placed the child theme under /wp-content/themes and titled it builder-child. Below you will find my code for my new style.css file placed in the builder-child directory.

```
/*
Theme Name:   Builder Child
Theme URI:    http://brewer2inspect.com/builder-child/  
Description:  Builder Child Theme
Author:       Mark G
Author URI:
Template:     builder
Version:      1.0.0
*/

// This @import line loads the stylesheet from the parent theme*/
@import url('../builder/style.css');

/* =Theme customization starts here ------- */
```

When this didn't work I took a look at the original or parent style.css and also tried changing the imports to reflect that file to the following that also didn't work.

```
@import url('assets/css/bootstrap.css');
@import url('assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css');
@import url('assets/css/docs.css');
@import url('assets/js/google-code-prettify/prettify.css');
@import url('assets/nivo/nivo-slider.css');
@import url('assets/css/prettyPhoto.css');
@import url('assets/css/options.css');
```

Comment: It is called builder.  The parent theme uses all lowercase letters.

Answer (score 0):

Just checking - is your parent theme called "builder" or "Builder"?  The import path is case-sensitive.

Comment: Also, the codex indicates that importing the parent theme stylesheets is no longer best practice: [link] (https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)

Comment: Or... Try changing the beginning // comment tag in the line '//This @import line loads the stylesheet from the parent theme */'  to /*.  (Or alternatively remove the end */)